# Azure Not Finding Partial View but Running Locally Does

Tags: c#, azure

I've been beating my head against a wall trying to figure out why my project loads these partials fine in Debug mode but when I publish to Azure it throws this error below.
Can someone smarter than me tell me why? I've Googled and searched Stack and couldn't find anything.

```
System.InvalidOperationException: The partial view '~/Views/Components/Partials/_Step1.cshtml' was not found. The following locations were searched:
    ~/Views/Components/Partials/_Step1.cshtml 
    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers.PartialTagHelper.ProcessAsync(TagHelperContext context, TagHelperOutput output)
       at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Runtime.TagHelpers.TagHelperRunner.<RunAsync>g__Awaited|0_0(Task task, TagHelperExecutionContext executionContext, Int32 i, Int32 count)
       at AspNetCore.Views_Components_Create.ExecuteAsync()
       at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RazorView.RenderPageCoreAsync(IRazorPage page, ViewContext context)
       at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RazorView.RenderPageAsync(IRazorPage page, ViewContext context, Boolean invokeViewStarts)
       at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RazorView.RenderAsync(ViewContext context)
       at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.ViewExecutor.ExecuteAsync(ViewContext viewContext, String contentType, Nullable`1 statusCode)
       at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.ViewExecutor.ExecuteAsync(ViewContext viewContext, String contentType, Nullable`1 statusCode)
       at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.ViewExecutor.ExecuteAsync(ActionContext actionContext, IView view, ViewDataDictionary viewData, ITempDataDictionary tempData, String contentType, Nullable`1 statusCode)
       at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.ViewResultExecutor.ExecuteAsync(ActionContext context, ViewResult result)
       at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewResult.ExecuteResultAsync(ActionContext context)
       at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeNextResultFilterAsync>g__Awaited|29_0[TFilter,TFilterAsync](ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
       at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResultExecutedContextSealed context)
       at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.ResultNext[TFilter,TFilterAsync](State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
       at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.InvokeResultFilters()
    --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
       at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeNextResourceFilter>g__Awaited|24_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
       at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResourceExecutedContextSealed context)
       at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
       at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.InvokeFilterPipelineAsync()
    --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
       at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAsync>g__Awaited|17_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task task, IDisposable scope)
       at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.<Invoke>g__AwaitRequestTask|6_0(Endpoint endpoint, Task requestTask, ILogger logger)
       at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
       at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
       at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try removing `~` from '~/Views/Components/Partials/_Step1.cshtml' and reuploading. So From

`'~/Views/Components/Partials/_Step1.cshtml'`

to

`'/Views/Components/Partials/_Step1.cshtml'`

Comment: Sadly, that did not work. Thank you for trying though.

Comment: try removing _ from _Step1.cshtml in a way that it must start with an alphabetic character.

Comment: Also try deleting everything on the server and republishing the whole project over again. Sometimes it solves such a situation.

Comment: I actually solved it by deleting the folder and recreating it. Dunno why the worked? I checked the project file and it had the files. Either way, thanks for the help.